# Advanced RegEx Help required

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a bit of an unusual requirement for replacing a string using regex... bear with me.

I have an input string...

#### Input

```html
<section className={some-class}>

Un-touched stuff here

</section>

<hr />
```

... and i'd like to replace parts of the string so the output ends up like this...

#### Output

```html
<!-- some-class -->

Un-touched stuff here

<hr />
```

**some-class** could be anything so i need to match and replace either side of the section, class name stuff.

Also the `<hr />` represents any other html which i also don't want to touch.

I have the below so far but it's not quite right because it also matches the `<` and `/>` around the `<hr />`

#### RegEx

```js
\<section className\=|\{|\}|\<|\/|section|\>
```

Comment: This might be sufficient [`<section\s+className[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/section>`](https://regex101.com/r/hbkLp8/2) if the untouched stuff does not contain nested section tags.

Comment: You might want to [read about](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) the limitations of regex when applied to HTML/XML.

Comment: Can `<section>`s be nested?  If so, can they be deeply nested?  Can they have additional attributes besides `className`?

Answer (score 1):

I hope the following helps you out:

[Test Regex here.](https://regex101.com/r/oyTgzH/7)

1. < matches <
2. [^ ]* matches everything before the next space (in this case it matches section)
3. [^=]*?= matches everything up until and including the next =
4. { matches {
5. ([^}]*?) matches and captures everything up until the next }
6. }> matches }>
7. ([^<]*) matches everything up until the next <
8. <\/ matches <\/
9. \1 matches the captured group from 5 (section)
10. > matches >
11. \s* matches all whitespace characters

```js
let str = `<section className={CLASS_A}>

  Un-touched stuff here

</section>

<hr />

<section className={CLASS_B}>

  Un-touched stuff here

</section>`;
let reg = /<([^ ]*)[^=]*?={([^}]*?)}>([^<]*)<\/\1>\s*/g
console.log(str.replace(reg, "<!-- $2 -->$3"));
```

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted, but I might have, as link-only answers are very much frowned on here.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I put a bunch of code there too. Js is not my native tongue, but I think this should do.

Comment: Code-only answers are also frowned upon, I'm afraid.  A good answer will often have some useful code, but should always have some explanatory text demonstrating how and why your technique solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Regex: `/<section\s+className={([^}]+)}\s*>([\s\S]*)<\/section>\s*/`

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q5xvYI/2/)

1. `<section` Match `<section`
2. `\s+` Match one or more whitespace characters
3. `className=` Match `className=`
4. `{` Match `{`
5. `([^}]+)` Capture Group 1: one or more non-`}` characters
6. `}` Match `}`
7. `\s*` Zero or more whitespace characters
8. `>` Match `>`
9. `([\s\S]*)` Capture Group 2: zero more characters of any type (whitespace or non-whitespace)
10. `<\/section>` Match `</section>`
11. `\s*` Match zero or more whitespace characters

```js
let str = `<section className={xxxx}>

Un-touched stuff here

</section>

<hr />
`;

let regex = /<section\s+className={([^}]+)}\s*>([\s\S]*)<\/section>\s*/;
console.log(str.replace(regex, '<!-- $1 -->\n$2'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies i missed two vital parts of information about my problem.

- The input will actually have multiple section tags
- The className is an enum so it will be inside curly braces

```js
enum CLASS_A = "class-a"
enum CLASS_B = "class-b"
```

#### Input

```html
<section className={CLASS_A}>

  Un-touched stuff here

</section>

<hr />

<section className={CLASS_B}>

  Un-touched stuff here

</section>
```

I've referenced both the above solutions and thanks to @Booboo and @wp78de and with some small adjustments the below regex seems to solve the problem.

https://regex101.com/r/hbkLp8/4

If there's a neater way please do share.

```js
/<section\s+className\=\{([^>]*)\}>([\s\S]*?)<\/section>\s*/gm
```

#### Output

```html
<!-- class-a -->


Un-touched stuff here

<hr />

<!-- class-b -->


Un-touched stuff here

<hr />
```